# Android 5.1 -How do i update the UI change when i change configuration from notification tray?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have a simple app that change that toggle the silent mode to normal or vice versa. But the problem is that i can just drag the notification tray can change the mode from silent to normal and i want the Volume icon inside the also change to normal icon.

In which state the application goes in when i pull down the Tray Notification ?

[image]

Now When i tap the mute to normal mode from tray, which method should i put my update method to reflect the changes.

The uiupdate

I tried callinf updateUI method onResume but doesn;t seems to work as the application doesn't seem to be pause.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.manis.silentmodetoggle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private AudioManager audioManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.v("myTest","called onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //reference to the audio manager
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        FrameLayout contentView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);

        updateUi();

        contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RingerHelper.performToggle(audioManager);
                updateUi();
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateUi(){
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        //Set The PhoneImage
        int phoneImage =RingerHelper.isPhoneSilent(audioManager) ? R.drawable.noaudio_96: R.drawable.highvolume_96 ;

        imageView.setImageResource(phoneImage);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.v("myTest","Called onStart");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.v("myTest","Called onResume");
        updateUi();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        Log.v("myTest","Called onPostResume");
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.v("myTest","Called onPause");
    } 
 }

package com.example.manis.silentmodetoggle;

import android.media.AudioManager;


public class RingerHelper {

    private RingerHelper(){};

    public static void performToggle(AudioManager audioManager)
    {
       //if the phone is currently silent then set ot normal
        //if normal then set to silent
        audioManager.setRingerMode(
                isPhoneSilent(audioManager)? AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL : AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT
        );
    }

    public  static  boolean isPhoneSilent(AudioManager audioManager){
        return audioManager.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT;

    }
}
```

ps:This is sample app from Android App development from dummies book.

Comment: So you know how to determine which state the ringer is in, you just need to know how to execute the code?

Comment: yaa.. Where to execute the Code ? isSilentMode detects the state of the ringer and updateui changes the ui according to the current state. But i can change the ringer state manually by dragging the notification tray but when i go back to the app the ui still show the old state. So in which activity lifecycle method should i put my code to change the UI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any direct callbacks when the notification tray is dragged down or pulled up. It's meant to be decoupled from the applications.  That being said, there are a couple things you might be able to try.

First, you could write a service that will poll for the ringer status periodically. Not the ideal solution, but this will definitely work.

Second, you could try implementing [onWindowFocusChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.Callback.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29), like so:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    if(hasFocus) {
        // check ringer status
    }

}
```

And if you want to be able to programmatically expand the status bar from your application, you can include this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

Comment: thanks! it worked. didn't added the permission & still works..may be i'm directly testing from Android Studio.

Comment: You don't need the permission to implement onWindowFocusChanged(), just to open and close the status bar programmatically.  Should have a been a bit clearer, sorry!